# Does the kernel of a morphism equal to its source object in an abelian category imply it is a zero map?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, abelian-categories, limits-colimits

Does the kernel of a morphism equals to its source object in abelian category implies this is a zero map?

Namely let $C$ be an abelian category, $X,Y$ are two objects, $f\in Hom_{C}(X,Y)$ is a morphism, then if $\ker(f)=X$, can we conclude $f$ is the zero map?

Comment: As the answer implicitly tells you, the question is flawed. The kernel of a morphism *not* an object, it is actually a morphism.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but from definition I think the kernel is an object together with a morphism plus the universal property, so does object really not matter? @MooS

Comment: When I say 'morphism' this automatically carries an object within its data. But it is false to think of the kernel as an object solely. For example if you say that the identity morphism is the kernel of $f: X \to Y$, then it is automatically clear that the underlying object of the kernel is $X$ without saying it.

Comment: Thanks! This question actually arose when I'm trying to prove Schur's Lemma in abelian catogory, namely, the morphism between simple object can only be zero or isomorphism. So the information provided is all about the object(which is simple),  then it will be naturally to think the kernel of this morphism is the subobject of its source object which is 0 or itself, then it will be natural to prove the kernel can only be 0 if original morphism is not 0, this naturalness make me think this should be true. So now I guess I should try some other ways to prove this lemma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean that the identity map $1_X:X\to X$ is the kernel of $f$, then yes.  By definition, if $k:K\to X$ is the kernel of $f$, $fk=0$ (and  $k$ is universal with this property).  So if $1_X$ is the kernel, then $0=f1_X=f$.

If you just mean that there is *some* morphism $g:X\to X$ which is a kernel of $f$, then no.  For instance, let $f:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/2$ be the quotient map in $Ab$ and leg $g:\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}$ be multiplication by $2$.  Then $g$ is a kernel of $f$, but $f\neq 0$.

Comment: Thank you for this easy counter example, otherwise I will still struggle to prove this is right.